# Dar estilo a log de errores que muestro por consola ASP NET.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Trabajo en ASP.NET Core 3.1, C#, Visual Studio 2019, SO Windows 10

Implemente un log de errores personalizado el cual muestro el log por `powerShell` integrado en el IDE de VS, pero he intentado darle `style` aplicando un `Theme` personalizado. El código es el siguiente:

```
public static class CustomConsoleThemes
{
    public static CustomConsoleTheme VisualStudioMacLight
    {
        get;
    } = new CustomConsoleTheme(new Dictionary<ConsoleThemeStyle, string>
    {
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Text] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.SecondaryText] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.TertiaryText] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Invalid] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Null] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Name] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.String] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Number] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Boolean] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.Scalar] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelVerbose] = "\u001b[30m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelDebug] = "\u001b[44;1m\u001b37;1m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelInformation] = "\u001b[42;1m\u001b37;1m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelWarning] = "\u001b[43;1m\u001b37;1m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelError] = "\u001b[41;1m\u001b37;1m",
        [ConsoleThemeStyle.LevelFatal] = "\u001b[46;1m\u001b37;1m"
    });
}
```

Otro archivo

```
public class CustomConsoleTheme : ConsoleTheme
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<ConsoleThemeStyle, string> _styles;

    public CustomConsoleTheme(IReadOnlyDictionary<ConsoleThemeStyle, string> styles)
    {
        if (styles == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(styles));
        }
        this._styles = styles.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
    }

    public static CustomConsoleTheme VisualStudioMacLight { get; } = CustomConsoleThemes.VisualStudioMacLight;

    public override bool CanBuffer
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    protected override int ResetCharCount { get; } = "\x0018[0m".Length;

    public override int Set(TextWriter output, ConsoleThemeStyle style)
    {
        string str;
        if (!this._styles.TryGetValue(style, out str))
            return 0;
        output.Write(str);
        return str.Length;
    }

    public override void Reset(TextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write("\x0018[0m");
    }
}
```

Lo llamo desde Program.cs

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggingConfiguration) => loggingConfiguration
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "CMS_APP")
                .Enrich.WithProperty("MachineName", Environment.MachineName)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("CurrentManagedThreadId", Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("OSVersion", Environment.OSVersion)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Version", Environment.Version)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("UserName", Environment.UserName)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("ProcessId", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("ProcessName", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName)
                .WriteTo.Console(theme: CustomConsoleTheme.VisualStudioMacLight)
                .WriteTo.File(formatter: new CustomTextFormatter(), path: Path.Combine(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + $"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Logs{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}", $"load_error_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd}.txt"))
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)); ;
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Esperaba el siguiente resultado me refiero a los colores que van dentro de los `[]`

[image: img]

Pero me esta saliendo así.

[image: img2]

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?